# Adding Action to the Action Bar Android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am trying to add a search icon to the action bar, and it shows up in the xml preview in Android Studio, but when I run my app it shows up in the overflow menu instead of an icon on the action bar. What am I doing wrong?

menu_launch.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".LaunchActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

I tried setting `app:showAsAction` to `"always"` but it did not work.

In my LaunchActivity.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_launch, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

My LaunchActivity.java extends Activity, not ActionBarActivity, I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Thank you for any help, this is my first app.

Comment: try    android:orderInCategory="100"  or app:showAsAction="always"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `ActionBarActivity`, you would use `app:showAsAction`, since it would be an AppCompat property.

For an `Activity`, you should use `android:showAsAction` since that is the only property that it reads.

If you want it to always appear as an icon, set the property to `"always"`.

Answer (score 0):

Have your Activity extend ActionBarActivity. The menu_launch.xml you have will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your theme. It depends on your theme too. 
in styles.xml file

```
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

let me know if that worked or not, because everything else seems working in your code. You need to also put this reference to manifest.xml file.
for your main activity

```
<application
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

according to the documentation..

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

This declares that the Search action should appear as an action button when room is available in the action bar, but the Settings action should always appear in the overflow. (***By default, all actions appear in the overflow, but it's good practice to explicitly declare your design intentions for each action.***)

So try to rotate your screen, your app will display it, whenever room is available for the icon to get fit in.
You should set showAsAction="always".

Answer (score 0):

```
Why you are sitting app:showAsAction="never" in action_settings try this

 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".LaunchActivity">

      <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
       android:title="@string/action_search"
       app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

       <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
  </menu>
```

or

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".LaunchActivity">

     <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

      <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
       android:title="@string/action_search"
       app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>


 </menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:showAsAction="never"`

`android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

these are the issues just change it to

`android:showAsAction="always"`

try changing `app:showAsAction` to `android:showAsAction`